# Oracle materialized view error

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have materialized views that ran in production but hare having problems refreshing. The error message is

> ORA-32411: materialized view definition query exceeds the maximum length

The ones that are having the problems are 76kb,70kb,75kb, and 67kb. Is there anything that can be done, besides splitting up the query? The scripts are one long query each so it will be hard to split up.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate your materialized views as just views, and then recompile your materialized view select statement as

```
select * from your_new_view
```

I don't believe there is a limit to how long a view can be. I've also found this makes updating the MV query quite simple as you only have to recompile the view instead of dropping and recreating the MV.